# Como pular linha após a vírgula de uma varível armazenada no banco MySql

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

Na arquivo view.php, preciso exibir um campo que já está armazenado no
banco de dados, do tipo *varchar*, mas ao exibir quero que o texto seja
apresentado pulando as linhas ao encontrar o caractere vírgula (,). Exemplo:

Texto armazenado na variável no Banco de Dados: 
 Poema é um gênero textual
dividido em estrofes e versos, cada estrofe é constituída por versos.

Resultado na view.php: 
Poema é um gênero textual dividido em estrofes e versos 
cada estrofe é constituída por versos.

```
<p align="justify"><?php echo $poema; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`**$array** = explode(',' ,$poema )` Essa é a lógica que deves seguir.

Estude sobre a função `explode()` Ela certamente resolve seu problema, só precisa depois criar um foreach ou algum loop para imprimir cada posição do `$array[0]`.

Explicando de forma básica o explode recebe 2 parâmetros:

`explode([o separador], [string a ser Destrinchada] )`

Bem da lógica de explodir mesmo, mas como se usasse o separador para mostrar aonde.